# How long is an experience?

Tags: time

What timescales of customer/user engagement do you consider during your design processes?

And why?

Comment: At least half as long as twice its length, if not more.

Comment: @RogerAttrill Oh, like the length of a rope you say?! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Anything from a fraction of a second to hours and hours of gaming. It all boils down to the scope of the application you're building. If your scope is to get the user to push a button to vote for something in an online Newspaper, then close to nothing. However, if your scope is like the Malmö/Sweden based King.com who published [Candy Crush Saga](http://www.candycrushsaga.com/) - then your goal is as long as possible and repeatedly. Hopefully users will continue spending money on digital content so King can make [$568 million in profit](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2014/02/18/king-digital-in-ipo-filing-crushes-it-on-revenue-profit/).

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather vague and open ended because it depends on your product.

However, generally speaking the customer experience lasts right from the moment they hear about your product until the last point at which they have any interaction with it.

This includes:

- word of mouth
- research about product
- pre sales support
- the buying experience
- immediate post sales interaction
- ownership
- support and maintenance including updates and upgrades
- end of product life

i.e. the complete life cycle of the product - these are all part of the memorable touchpoints of customer experience, and define how customers consume and share your product and your brand.

This could range from minutes to 100 years depending on your actual product.

For more reading I recommend: Lior Arussy's "Customer Experience Strategy: The Complete Guide from Innovation to Execution", which although rather dry and wordy, is full of priceless insight.

Answer (score 0):

Cynically I could answer "it depends how much they're paying for", the less flippant answer would be there is no exact timescale. The design and acceptance process would end when the stakeholders are happy that a design caters for their needs.

Now, that said, experience dictates that you get used to the types of projects you get asked to do and can take an educated guess that a simple few pages of a process form mock and investigation will take 3 days and use that going forward.

The short answer is it varies wildly on the complexity of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think either you missunderstood or the question isn't clear - I meant to ask about the lenght of experience for users not how long the design process lasts.